# mySQL Passes RESULT but INSERT not happening

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert

I have a form that submits to itself.  On submit, a query is generated and run and if ($result) then I make $success = 1 to use in a jQuery function that submits an email and then closes the form.  The jQuery function is dependent on the $success value echoed being '1' to trigger.  Recently I had someone submit the form, the email was generated, but the insert query did not appear to enter anything into the database.

The PHP code:

```
require_once ('inc/dbconnect.php');
include ('inc/dataFormat.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {

    $qins = sprintf('INSERT INTO becmtrack (siteName, siteNum, location, cluster, enodeName, upgDate, tech, techNum, becm, becmFail, ecm1, ecm2, ecm3, dateAlu, aluContact, aluContNum, trackNum, comment) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',  [VALUES ARE HERE]);
    $rins = mysqli_query($dB, $qins) or die('Error in query => ' . $qins . '<br />' . mysqli_error($dB));

    $success = ($rins) ? 1 : 0;

}
```

The jQuery code (inside a document ready function):

```
if ("<? echo $success; ?>" == 1) {
   var mailBody = 'Site Name: <? echo $_POST['siteName2'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0ASite Number: <? echo $_POST['siteNum'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0ALocation Code: <? echo $_POST['location'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0AeCEMs Removed: <? echo $_POST['ecm1'] . ', ' . $_POST['ecm2'] . ', ' . $_POST['ecm3'];?>';
<? if ($_POST['dateAlu'] != '') { ?>
   mailBody += '%0ADate Cards Returned to Company: <? echo $_POST['dateAlu'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0AALU Contact: <? echo $_POST['aluContact'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0AContact Number: <? echo $_POST['aluContNum'];?>';
   mailBody += '%0AShipping Tracking Number (if applicable): <? echo $_POST['trackNum'];?>';
<? } ?>
$('#reloadTrig',window.opener.document).trigger('click');
window.open('mailto:email.address@somecompany.com?subject=eNodeB%20bCEM%20Upgrade%20Completed&body='+mailBody);
if ('<? echo $_POST['addmore'];?>' != 'addmore') {
window.close();
    }
}
```

Is there someway for this code to generate a valid result without the data being inserted into the database?

Comment: You're using `mysqli`, but have failed to use the [SQL placeholder feature](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid massive [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Using it like `mysql_query` is dangerous and reckless. You should be using [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to do your escaping. `sprintf` should not be used to construct queries like this.

Comment: See below, all sprintf parameters are escaped via a sanitizing function.

Comment: Placeholders are a very standard, reliable, trustworthy way of doing this. What you've got here is unconventional and might lead to severe security problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query after a successful connection to database is in most of the cases true, according to this documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

`Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`

---

You need to check out if there's really an inserted row.

According to the documentation here (and a given example)

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

You can check either by mysqli_commit (which in the example fails for duplicated entry, not for syntax error):

`$all_query_ok ? $mysqli->commit() : $mysqli->rollback();`

or via mysqli_affected_rows (which will only be true, if the insert statement really inserts a row)

```
$result_query = @mysqli_query($query, $connect);
            if (($result_query == false) &&
               (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0))
```

Comment: This still looks like I wouldn't pass my result test without the INSERT happening.  Checking for an affected row is a good additional test.  Would it make sense to just add that as an additional test, leaving the original test intact?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling **mysqli_commit**  just after insert.

**P.S.** You shouldn't use sprintf to pass parameters, that won't escape them.
You should use **mysqli_prepare** for that, or just call **mysqli_real_escape_string** arount every parameter.

You can make function:

```
function escapeArray($arr)
{
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($arr as $value)
     $ret []=mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Good function, but I think it needs some more sanitization according to the value type. For example `if(is_int($value) { $ret [] = (int) $value; }`

Comment: All of my sprintf parameters pass through a sanitizing function.  They were not included in the post due to length and I didn't think it was relevant.